# Android - Checkboxes in ListView lose their status when user open/hide soft keyboard

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter, android-softkeyboard

I implemented a custom ArrayAdapter to manage my data and show it in a ListView.
This is the code of my custom adapter:

```
private class ViewHolder{

    User user;
    CheckBox check;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    User c = getItem(position);

    if(convertView==null)
        convertView=new userCheckableRow(getContext(),c.getChecked());
    CheckBox name = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userCheckBox);


    name.setText(c.getName());
    holder.user=c;
    holder.check=name;
    name.setChecked(holder.user.getChecked());
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)((View)v.getParent().getParent()).getTag();
            CheckBox ck=holder.check;
            User c=(User) holder.user;
            c.setChecked(ck.isChecked());

       }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

In my activity the user fills some fields and check some checkboxes;
when he check them and then open/close keyboard to continue filling other fields, then the checkbox status is lost and these become all unchecked.

**What I tried (and didn't work):**

- Set an OnFocusChangedListener to all EditText fields to intercept when they get focus;
- Set an OnKeyListener to all EditText fields to intercept KEYCODE_BACK event;
- Implement onBackPressed();
- Implement a GlobalLayoutListener ([How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)) to intercept when keyboard is open, but with this code my checkboxes where unclickable because of continuous refreshing list;
- Implement onConfigurationChanged() to listen to keyboardHides|screenResize , but this callback event can intercept only hard keyboard and however didn't work;

How can I manage this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Read and try to understand this example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Also your ViewHolder class should be "static".

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Activity tag inside Manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```